How to log cron errors in WordPress?
I am having issues with my WordPress cron jobs failing at times and there being no logs written to error_log.
I'm on a Bitnami WordPress instance if it matters, mostly default settings.
It doesn't log, even when it's a PHP syntax error or the like as I've deliberately tested for this. My logs work fine otherwise, just not in WordPress crons.
